# Inflating ViewPager from XML layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, runtimeexception

I am following the [Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/android-programming.html) and there is an example using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) through the 2 files:

The file [res/values/ids.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/CriminalIntent/res/values/ids.xml) defines an id in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="viewPager" />
</resources>
```

And the Java source file [CrimePagerActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/CriminalIntent/src/de/afarber/criminalintent/CrimePagerActivity.java) uses that id:

```
public class CrimePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);
```

I have tried to change the example to have a `ViewPager` object being inflated from an XML layout file **res/layout/crime_pager.xml** (instead of just using an id):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then I am trying to use that object in the **CrimePagerActivity.java**:

```
public class CrimePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.crime_pager);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and fails with a `RuntimeException` and little info (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI3AQ.png)):

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

What is the problem here please?

Comment: post stack trace please!

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot - there is no stack trace

Comment: as you can see it says the device is disconnected :-). connect it correctly and run it then copy and paste the logcat and put it in your question.

Comment: No, I don't have a real device, but I am using a simulator. I've tried it both on Windows and Mac - and there is no stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
<ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager" />
```

to

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```